# AWS RDS doesn't seem to be stopping even after terminating the instance; (added a screenshot)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am a beginner in using AWS. I was able to make use of the AWS documentation for setting up EC2 and RDS for deploying my personal website using the Free Tier quota. After I was done using the service I stopped both the instances. Towards the end of the month, even after I stopped both the instances, I was sent an alert regarding the 85% usage of my Free Tier quota. So I checked the AWS Billing (screenshot added below) and tried finding where the RDS was taking up over 17GB of data out of max limit of 20GB. To me this is not making sense as I had already terminated the RDS instance. If you can spot what I'm doing wrong here— thank you!

Link for screenshot: [i.stack.imgur.com/m53BU.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m53BU.png)

Comment: If you terminated the RDS instance then I suspect the storage costs are related to DB snapshots.

Comment: @jarmod No. I had not opted for the snapshots. I just checked again and can verify that there are no snapshots.

Comment: Any chance that the listed 17 GB-Mo is simply your use of storage for this month up to the point that you terminated the RDS instance (after which it will not increase)?

Comment: @jarmod I wanted to wait before answering the question to check that. I can now confirm that that is not the case. The actual usage went up from **87.06%** to **87.34%** even after having terminated the RDS instance. I don't think this will exceed 100% by the end of the month but will again reset and start over. Still no clue of what's happening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Post Update:**

> My issue has been resolved!

Here's what had happened:- I was sent an email regarding 85% usage of my AWS resource for Free Tier. This was a day during the month of June. Right after, I immediately headed to stop all my instances. After that it still didn't seem to have stopped because the dashboard kept showing the updated usage limit which happened to keep increasing day after day. After the month got over, the very next day, on the 1st of July the dashboard cleared out with all instances gone! Wiped away. Cleared. Relief. Finally. Phew!! End of story.